# wmic /failfast does nothing

Tags: batch-file, wmic

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (


     wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:%%a /user: /password: computersystem get Name, domain, Manufacturer, Model, NumberofProcessors, PrimaryOwnerName,Username, Roles, totalphysicalmemory /format:list
     wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:%%a /user: /password: cpu get Name, Caption, MaxClockSpeed, DeviceID, status /format:list
     wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:%%a /user: /password: path Win32_VideoController get Name, status, DeviceID /format:list
     wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:%%a /user: /password: os get Version, Caption, CountryCode, CSName, Description, InstallDate, SerialNumber, ServicePackMajorVersion, WindowsDirectory /format:list
     wmic /FAILFAST:ON /node:%%a /user: /password: csproduct get identifyingnumber /format:list


    ) >%%a.txt
```

This is my code and it works like it should do, but the `/FAILFAST:ON` it does skip to next if you wait 10-20 sec, I need it to go faster to scan large systems, anybody got any ideas?

Could I use an if command that pings with 1 packet and goes to next if no response ?

thanks to JosefZ:

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (
  set "_ready="
  for /F %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%a^|find "TTL="') do set "_ready=%%G"
  if defined _ready (
      rem your `WMIC /FAILFAST:OFF /node:%%a …` 
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: computersystem get Name, domain, Manufacturer, Model, NumberofProcessors, PrimaryOwnerName,Username, Roles, totalphysicalmemory /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: cpu get Name, Caption, MaxClockSpeed, DeviceID, status /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: path Win32_VideoController get Name, status, DeviceID /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: os get Version, Caption, CountryCode, CSName, Description, InstallDate, SerialNumber, ServicePackMajorVersion, WindowsDirectory /format:list
         wmic /node:%%a /user: /password: csproduct get identifyingnumber /format:list

  )>"%%a.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [`/FAILFAST` switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787035(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Whether or not the `/NODE` computers are checked before trying to
>   execute the `WMIC` commands against them. When `FAILFAST` is `ON`,
>   `WMIC` pings the computers in the `/NODE` switch before sending `WMIC`
>   commands to them. If they do not respond to the ping, the `WMIC`
>   commands are not executed for them.

One log file for each server:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (
  set "_ready="
  for /F %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%a^|find "TTL="') do set "_ready=%%G"
  if defined _ready (
      rem your `WMIC /FAILFAST:OFF /node:%%a …` commands here
  )>"%%a.txt"
)
```

or the only log file for all servers:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ip.txt) do (
  set "_ready="
  for /F %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %%a^|find "TTL="') do set "_ready=%%G"
  if defined _ready (
      rem your `WMIC /FAILFAST:OFF /node:%%a …` commands here
  )
)>"logservers.txt"
```

Comment: thanks ! it worked, the batch file now skips unresponding ip addresses