# batch skip computer if "rpc server is not responding"

Tags: batch-file, skip

Hi all I'm doing the inventory, and I need to get the info about a whole ton of computers. Going to each and every is not an option, and this is why I created the batch file where I type in the computer name and get all info I need on that computer, and then the batch is asking if I want to get info about the next computer. If I type in "y", it's asking for the name of the next computer, and it keeps giving you the info about computers until I hit "n" in which case the command prompt window closes. So, what I want to do, is if the computer is off, or offline, or unavailable for some other reason; if I get the message: "

Node - (computername)

ERROR:

Description = The RPC server is unavailable.

", I'd like to skip that program. In fact, if possible, if the computer isn't responding in, say, 3 seconds, I'd like to skip that computer. That is, something like "if (this message shows up) goto :anothercomputer"

I'm sure it's possible to implement, I just don't know how. I know very, very, very little about batch scripting, and I'm not talking about scripting in general... All I learned I learned from the Internet, but there's so much to learn yet...

P.S. I'm using wmic /user /password /node (commandname) to get all info, if that matters.

P.P.S. I'm quite new to Stack Overflow, so please keep that in mind.

```
:Start 

@echo off 

set /p password="Password:" 

:Nextcomp 

set /p computer="Computer name:" 

wmic /user:username /password:%password% /node:"%computer%" memorychip get capacity 

set /P c=Do you want to get info about another computer (y/n)? 

if /I "%c%" EQU "y" goto :Nextcomp 

if /I "%c%" EQU "n" goto :End goto :choice 

pause 

:End
```

Update: Is it possible to show just, say, "4 GB" or at least "4" instead of "4294967296"? Because I'm getting the info about the hard drive capacity, and it's quite a pain to divide the large number by 1073741824 (1024*1024*1024) to get the sizes in GB. (I mean, for 1 computer, it's quite all right, but for 100 or more - that's quite a lot of math to do... And it's easier to divide by 1024 3 times rather than by another large number that is hard to remember)

Comment: As you're new here, and based upon what is above, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We expect you to provide your code, explain exactly what it is about it which doesn't work as intended, and what you've tried yourself in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**ComputerList.txt** Use IP or name eg

```
127.0.0.1
MyComputer
```

Then (`/failfast` means if it's not turned on it doesn't wait)

```
wmic /failfast:on /user:username /password:%password% /node:@"C:\computerList.txt" memorychip get capacity /Format:csv
```

To make ComputerList.txt

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> ComputerList.txt
```

Comment: You are missing a parameter with `failfast`.

Comment: Doesn't look like [FailFast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311043/1417694) does what people think it does.

Comment: COM uses RPC for calling remotely or into ActiveX EXE files.

Comment: The default RPC timeout is 720 seconds (12 mins).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it some time later. But I think it should work!